# Security for user-generated content in Phonegap app using access origin

Tags: php, cordova, security

My app displays some user-generated content and I also need to allow HTML tags. What I was wondering: When setting the config.xml file to only allow my own server - is there sill a way a user/hacker could somehow steal data? On a normal webpage you could insert a script to send some data to another server. But in my case, it is impossible to get this user's data to a 3rd party server. Or am I missing something? (And yes, I will still use a php script to remove some html entities. So this is just a question about if it is possible and not about if it is a good idea to trust other users)

Answer (score 0):

Any attacker in the world can send any data imaginable, valid or invalid, to your app, regardless of what controls you believe are in place, and there is nothing you can do to prevent them from sending anything.

As soon as you believe you've found a way to stop them, they can simply reverse engineer your client (step 1: download the .apk, step 2: JD-GUI, step 3: ???? step 4: pwnage) to allow them whatever capabilities they desire.

If you need to allow *some* HTML, but don't want to be vulnerable to XSS attacks, the traditional solution is to use [HTML Purifier](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier) on output when serving data to the end user.

If HTML Purifier is too slow, check out [Stauros](https://github.com/ircmaxell/Stauros). Stauros is narrowly focused on XSS prevention, while HTML Purifier has a broader goal of outputting standards-compliant HTML.

Comment: So let's say a hacker wants to grab a variable and send it to his server in order to do sth with it. How could he achieve this? Because of my access origin settings, the script cannot contact any 3rd party servers...

Comment: Access origin settings only affect clients connecting to your website. If he's trying to grab a variable and send it to his server, he simply grabs it then sends it in a separate request. If you're concerned about server-side variables, that's a wholly separate issue.